# How to Unlock Microsoft Office Access Record-locking Information?

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

i'm news in Access, i made a change today and then testing, my Access database stopped responding, The lock is still on the record in the database. Now I cannot get back into the database. How can I unlock this record to continue my changes?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNDs1.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWkzg.png

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to simply delete the .laccdb file. If not, reboot your computer and try again.

If you still can't delete it, someone else has a lock on it.